# ESP-WROOM-32 unable to flash with auto-program UART

Tags: esp32

I just made a custom schematic and PCB with an ESP-WROOM-32 module. The board has a USB-UART chip (CP2102) and an auto-program circuitry to flash firmware without pressing buttons, but it doesn't work: `esptool.py` stops with

```
Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Here are the relevant parts on my schematic:

[image: Programmer on custom ESP32-based board]

[image: Programmer on custom ESP32-based board]

I tried desoldering Q1 and Q2 and put two pushbuttons (+ pullups) and I could verify that the TX/RX lines are working, as I could flash a firmware.

I took the schematic from the [LOLIN32 board](https://arduino-projekte.info/download/sch_lolin32_v1.0.0.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The LOLIN32 schematic shows C6 with a too large capacity (1uF). That is important for the timing, as the auto-program circuitry needs to assert `EN` for the right amount of time.

In the [reference schematic](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/ESP32-Core-Board-V2_sch.pdf) it's just 1nF:

[image]

The [WEMOS D32](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/_static/files/sch_d32_v1.0.0.pdf) uses 100nF:

[image]

As I had an 100nF capacitor, I used that as a replacement and the auto-circuitry finally started working.

Comment: Hi were you able to fix the issue? I’m having an issue work custom PCB similar and I can’t flash. I can confirm TX and RX are working fine but can’t flash.

Comment: @VAAA in addition to check C6's value, ensure that the WROOM32 is soldered correctly. In my case I had to rework the solder on the bottom side pads, as some of them are connected to the flash chip but were shorted together, likely because the solder paste under the module didn't melt completely.

Comment: Very interesting. Will try that